# Do diatomic molecules undergo hybridization

Tags: hybridization

For the steric number to be 1,the molecule must be diatomic or linear in geometry and shape.

First of all, do they undergo hybridization?

Secondly, Just like the hybridization for steric number 2 is sp and for steric number 3 is sp2, what is the hybridization for steric number 1.

Answer (score 3):

Hybridization is a technique that has been invented by Linus Pauling for explaining the angles and the geometric shape of the polyatomic molecules. As diatomic molecules are always linear, without any angle, hybridization is not necessary for explaining their geometry.

Comment: I agree with that. Sometimes it is helpful though. Like in oxygen, the mixing of s and p orbitals to create a bond that is lower in energy then the pi bonds is easier to understand  with hybridisation. But for the general case: yes, don't use it where you don't need it. You'll get an up-goat from me.

Comment: As a typo that's almost as good as cow-orkers. Will try to use it in future.

Comment: @Ian the pun was indeed intended. But it is a very old and brief one (and I didn't even spell it right). https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=3229&q=upgoat

Comment: It might not be necessary to explain geometry but it helps explain some molecular properties. AOs are fine but MOs are different.